# SQL Python services error : attributeerror: module 'cryptography.utils' has no attribute 'enum'

Tags: python, sql-server, window, sql-server-2019, ssms-2016

At work, we use SQL Server 2019 which while setting up we included the SQL server Machine learning service so that we can run python script through our SSMS. We use the python script to import data from our salesforce end into our database.  Prior to this day everything is working very perfect, until this morning that the job failed, and the error below popped up:

```
  Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 15
An external script error occurred: 
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, serialization
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\serialization\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives._serialization import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\_serialization.py", line 15, in <module>
    class PBES(utils.Enum):
AttributeError: module 'cryptography.utils' has no attribute 'Enum'

SqlSatelliteCall error: Error in execution.  Check the output for more information.
```

I thought the library namely (`cryptography`) is outdated, so I tried to upgrade the library from the Command Prompt as Administrator and this below error comes:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions' (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\PYTHON_SERVICES\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\exceptions.py)
```

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2019, why are you *still* using SSMS 16? SSMS 16 only supports SQL Server 2008-2016. You should be at least using the last release of SSMS 18, or (probably better) the latest version of SSMS, which is currently 19.3.